# Disable WADL endpoint generation in swagger documentation using springdoc-openapi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a spring boot application that has swagger documentation enabled using springdoc-openapi. For some reason there is an endpoint called /application.wadl is getting created automatically without adding any logic. Is there any way to disable wadl endpoints? I didn't add specific Wadl configuration in application.yml file as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround after looking into the springdoc-openapi documentation. We can use **springdoc.packages-to-scan** property to scan only controller package as shown below

```
springdoc:
   packages-to-scan:
    - com.test.appName.controller
```